# Nested Foreach loops using 2 lists in same pipeline

Tags: powershell, foreach, nested, pipe, pipeline

I'm looking to source variables from two different lists, and match them to a text out-file. They will always be associated, line for line.

```
$promos = Get-Content \\path\Promo_Collection.csv
$descriptions = Get-Content \\path\Description_Collection.csv

foreach ( $promo in $promos ) {  
foreach ( $description in $descriptions ) {  
"Promo: " + $promo + " " + "Description: " + $description | Out-File -Width 4096 \\path\Test_$promo.txt -encoding ASCII  
}   }
```

The output I get is the following:
Test_promo1.txt
Promo: Promo1 Description: Description1

Test_promo2.txt
Promo: Promo2 Description: Description1

and so on... I've tried several ways (breaks, tags) to iterate the 2nd foreach loop, and keep it in the same pipeline as the 1st foreach loop without success. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: If you like to match the elements of one CSV file to the elements of the other CSV file you have to match them before you output them. At the moment you simply iterate through all of them for each element. Take a look at the cmdlet `Compare-Object`. It is made for comparison of objects.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to loop over both collections, something like the following should do the trick

```
$promos = Get-Content \\path\Promo_Collection.csv
$descriptions = Get-Content \\path\Description_Collection.csv
while ($promos)
{
    $p, $promos = $promos
    $d, $descriptions = $descriptions
    "Promo: $p Description: $d" | 
        Out-File -Width 4096 \\path\Test_$p.txt -encoding ASCII
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Vadim and Bruce for your responses. I feel my question wasn't worded very well and appreciate you trying to piece it together. In the end I did the following, which seems to be working. The Combined_Collection.csv is a multi-column report that maps promos and descriptions in a standard csv file.

```
$promos = Get-Content \\path\Promo_Collection.csv
$descriptionlist = @(Import-Csv -Path \\path\Combined_Collection.csv)  

foreach ( $promo in $promos ) { 
$description = $descriptionlist | Where-Object { $_.promo_code -eq $promo } | ForEach-Object { $_.description }  
...do some stuff  
}
```